# Is there a way to disallow runtime errors to crash app on background thread?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm running a method in this way

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in
        ...
})
```

I want this logic to avoid crashing app if something goes wrong inside. Is there any way to do so?

Please don't answer fix the bug if any, I'm talking about any potencial bug I haven't found. This runs on a timer to process data from server, if crashes, it will make app unusable since it will crash at start up.

App can live without this data processing in worst case, but crashing app on start up is much more worse since app can't be used at all.

I know Swift doesn't have a catch for unexpected exceptions but maybe there is a way to avoid background threads to crash app if things goes wrong

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, no, no.  Speaking as someone who has had to deal with legacy apps built by other people who thought this would be a good idea to do, please do not under any circumstance do this.  Just don't.  Do not do this at all.  There is no reason.  Fix the bug, or leave the crash.  But what you're asking to do is HIDE the bug which is entirely unacceptable.  Not to mention... the only way to do what you're asking means orphaning the entire thread (and therefore leaking ALL of the memory allocated on that thread).   ***DO NOT DO THIS!!***

Comment: This app is for a 4 days event, if it crashes because an unexpected bug I'll probably won't have the chance to fix it in time, why do you think you have the absolute truth? I'm obviously talking about bugs I haven't found...

Comment: You need to find a way to fail without crashing, so start by removing all your force-unwrapping code.

Comment: I don't feel very confortable with Swift, in any other laguage I worked on, I'd have the chance to put a catch to handle any unexpected exception and do my logging or anything in there, Swift philosofy seems to be done for people that can't fail

Comment: I believe the worst language to force programmers for a extra defensive programming is a language used on mobile since you don't have the chance to do a fast hot fix, you need to pass app store review without exception. Event with expedited review, this could take a day

Comment: You can write your app in Objective-C.

Comment: how that would help? Objective-C is worse tan Swift in relation to error handling. I hope I'll see the day where Swift allow exception handling in non useless way. Thanks man

Comment: "This app is for a 4 days event" Do you mean some kind of coding marathon that you're involved in right now? What is it that you're doing that you expect to cause a crash?

Comment: @Josh Caswell: it seems nothing you have done ever had a bug :) I'm processing some bad formed data and it's hard to predict all different options, I'm trying to do my logic as defensive as posible but I'm just a human being and I can oversee an option

Comment: You're trying to make your comments as defensive as possible. I wasn't attacking you, just asking for more information. (Though I have to agree with nhgrif.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: it's just that I can't believe no one else (at least among people commenting here) thinks this exception handling mechanism is horrible, have you ever programmed on JAVA or C#? Probably you would understand the difference.

Comment: Java and C# throw exceptions for lots of errors that are able to be recovered form and are acceptable to catch.  Other than a few old APIs and KVO, Swift and Obj-C only throw exceptions in the case of programmer errors that can't be reasonably recovered from and use `NSError`s in places where Java and C# would be throwing exceptions.

Comment: By using `if let` you should be able to write crash free code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo what @nhgrif is saying, this is a really bad idea, something I would only consider if it were a case of a large body of uncontrolled code, ie., code from somebody else where I do not have the ability to fix the bug.

Two options I can think of:

1. Run the processing in a separate process, where failure of the process will result in the child process terminating, but won't terminate the parent process.
2. Assuming you're running on a *nix platform, either iOS, MacOS, Linux, etc., the same `signal` and `sigaction` calls you would use to catch these exceptions in C, C++, etc., are available, so you might be able to use that to handle exceptional situations and perhaps terminate more gracefully.

Again, both of these really feel like horrendous ideas, in violation of much of one of the basic principles of Swift, which is that runtime failures are fatal and  should be fixed, not worked around.

Comment: I like this answer, but neither option is available in iOS (unless I'm miss understanding the second answer).  I know of a way to do what this user is asking... but I refuse to share that knowledge because there's no good reason to do it...

Comment: So Swift philosofy is: if you made a mistake, you're done? If a bug made it to production build and causes app to crash you can only cry? If I were able to put a catch without a try I could do send a log to crashlystics, handle bug gracelly and act in consecuence without crashing app

Comment: No.  The Swift philosophy is... the language prevents a LOT of crashes at compile time just by nature of the language, there are a lot of excellent automated testing tools to catch bugs before production, and there are great libraries like Crashlytics/Fabric.IO to help with the few bugs that do make it to production.

Comment: `signal` (really `sigaction` since `signal` is superseded and calls `sigaction`) should be available on iOS.  A separate process is not.

Comment: And, while `sigaction` is available, I'm really not sure how you'd get it to do what you want since `setjmp` and `longjmp` probably don't work real well.

Comment: @nhgrif yeah, but use `sigaction` not `signal`.  The latter has been superseded for 20 some years.

Comment: A really simple test implies that `setjmp/longjmp` work as well, but they probably result in massive memory leaks.

Comment: @DavidBerry Well, I don't know about `setjmp` or `longjmp`.  There is a way to accomplish this though, and yes, this is going to involve leaking all the memory on whatever thread crashed with no chance of recovering it.

Comment: @nhgrif maybe not, `setjmp/longjmp` should be implemented for C++ and the standards for it require that they do proper memory unwinding (I think?)  So it might work for swift also, depending on implementation.  In any case it's a really ugly thing to do in any language.  And my really simple tests seem to imply that after you've used `setjmp` creating new objects is problematic at best (it's crashing on me)